# Bind enclosing control to dependency object's DP in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatemplate, attached-properties

Being blocked for multiple days searching I gave up and want to ask you for advice.

I have the following DataTemplate:

```
<TextBox x:Name="FilterValueTextBox"
                 Grid.Column="1"
                 BorderThickness="1"
                 BorderBrush="{Binding TextBoxBorderBrush}"
                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                 IsEnabled="{Binding FilterTypeValid}"
                 Background="{Binding TextBoxBackgroundBrush}"
                 VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                 Text="{Binding RawText}"
                 SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <controls:OnScreenKeyboardControl.KeyboardDescriptor>
                    <controls:KeyboardDescriptor TextBoxRef="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}}}" />
    </controls:OnScreenKeyboardControl.KeyboardDescriptor>
</TextBox>
```

The KeyboardDescriptor is a `DependencyObject` containing the Dependency Property `"TextBoxRef"` of type `TextBox`.

Exactly this mechanism works everywhere in my application EXCEPT this special case, where the binding should happen from within a datatemplate.

I read dozens of articles that state that everything up there is not part of the Visual or Logical Tree in the first place and thus, ELementName and RelativeSource Binding should fail.

Obviously I managed to reliably confirm this.
With the above I get the exception on template instantiation that "A two-way binding ( which is default in this case ) requires a path or x-path"...
Without the above binding attempt, the exception is gone, but of course the link is not established.

My question now is: Can I somehow pass the enclosing TextBox as a reference into the keyboard descriptor attached propertie's DP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOlved by myself. Changed above xaml to:

```
<TextBox x:Name="FilterValueTextBox"
                 Grid.Column="1"
                 BorderThickness="1"
                 BorderBrush="{Binding TextBoxBorderBrush}"
                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                 IsEnabled="{Binding FilterTypeValid}"
                 Background="{Binding TextBoxBackgroundBrush}"
                 VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                 Text="{Binding RawText}"
                 SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <controls:OnScreenKeyboardControl.KeyboardDescriptor>
                    <controls:KeyboardDescriptor TextBoxRef="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}}, Path=.}" />
    </controls:OnScreenKeyboardControl.KeyboardDescriptor>
</TextBox>
```

Nevertheless, thank you very much! Hope this can help someone else someday.